# Why is my DNS not resolving my website's IP?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, dns

I have a laptop with windows 7 OS. and I am unable to access my own website: http://dreampsychics.com, as well as the subdomain: http://www.admin.dreampsychics.com. I have a DSL connection and ISP is Century Link. My web host is saying they can see both sites.  For me, the sites are only accessible through a free proxy, or by using OpenDNS. My host thinks it is related to century link. After troubleshooting they told me to reset the modem to factory settings. So that is done and I still cannot access either of the sites unless I use an OpenDNS. I cannot get any results when I ping the url's, nor can I do a tracert.  Here is the nslookup I did:

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup dreampsychics.com
Server:  PK5001Z.PK5001Z
Address:  192.168.0.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to PK5001Z.PK5001Z timed-out
```

I am not a pro in solving DNS issues and don't know what else to do.

Comment: Have you recently made changes to your DNS records?  The TTL is set for 24 hrs, so you'll need to wait at least 24 hours for the caches to expire.

Comment: You could also try rebooting your router (since its acting as a caching DNS server) and flushing your computer's DNS (`ipconfig /flushdns`)

Comment: I'd recommend you to use an open DNS server, like [Google's][https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/] `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Answer (score 4):

You could try changing your modem or router settings to use a different DNS server(s).

To test, you could try forcing your `nslookup` to use a different DNS server for one lookup:

```
nslookup dreampsychics.com 8.8.8.8
```

If that returns the correct IP address, your router is likely picking up the default DNS server your ISP provides, which might be the CenturyLink DNS server.  I'd recommend changing DNS servers to use OpenDNS or [Google servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

ISP DNS servers tend to be slow and unreliable in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Your domain is entirely broken (**status: SERVFAIL**), neither DNS server you specify in your zone file is reachable, and part of the problem is both NS records you've put in are resolving to the same IP address.  The only reason the dreampsychics.com name is working at all is *you have it registered to an entirely different set of name servers* at your registrar...  you have some reading to do if you want to set this up right (i.e., google "DNS and BIND", read chapters 1-5).

```
$ dig @a.gtld-servers.net any dreampsychics.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rpz2+rl.13214.22-P2-Ubuntu-1:9.9.3.dfsg.P2-4 <<>> @a.gtld-servers.net any dreampsychics.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38710
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dreampsychics.com.             IN      ANY

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dreampsychics.com.      172800  IN      NS      dns1.livecybercash.org.
dreampsychics.com.      172800  IN      NS      dns2.livecybercash.org.

;; Query time: 165 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:503:a83e::2:30#53(2001:503:a83e::2:30)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 26 17:05:34 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 101
```

.

```
$ dig any www.admin.dreampsychics.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rpz2+rl.13214.22-P2-Ubuntu-1:9.9.3.dfsg.P2-4 <<>> any www.admin.dreampsychics.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 43079
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.admin.dreampsychics.com.   IN      ANY

;; Query time: 4008 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 26 16:53:29 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

.

```
$ checksoa dreampsychics.com

     Serial #   RTT(ms)  Version                       Nameservers (name, IP, SOA mname field) for dreampsychics.com

       TIMEOUT           --                            ns2.dedicatedpanel.com                62.75.212.215                      SOA:
       TIMEOUT           --                            ns1.dedicatedpanel.com                62.75.212.215                      SOA:
```